# How to say "Problem Management" as a profession in Chinese?

Tags: translation, terminology

So, 问题管理 (Problem Management / Issue Management) is a profession. How would I say:

- My profession is Problem Management?
- I am a Problem Management-er?

Can I just say 我工作是问题管理？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the 主管/ 经理 (supervisor/ manager)'s job to manage problems. If your job is to provide solutions to solve problems for the company, but don't have the power of a supervisor, then you would be a  问题管理顾问 (Problem Management Consultant) or 问题管理专家 (Problem Management Specialist)